# how to create non-debuggable release build for android using cordova command line

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, build, release

**cordova version 6 
with gradle 2.3.1**
I have generated the release build using command
**cordova build --release android**
,signed the apk using
**release-signing.properties** file which is in folder platforms/android,
in Android menifest file there is no attribute like application:android:debuggable="true/false" when I tried to make it false it throwing error: Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one [HardcodedDebugMode] 
so what we have to do so that generated apk(release version) will not be debuggable either on emulator or on real device

Answer (score 1):

If your are using gradle the release build is default non-debuggable and you can add it explicitly to your build.gradle :

```
  buildTypes {
            release {
                ...
                debuggable false
                ...
            }
}
```

Comment: thnks for answer , I tried that but still i am able to debug the apk using chrome://inspect ,I have installed build in the genymotion emulator.

Comment: you can debug your release using chrome://inspect if you use "debuggable true" in buildTypes release